# PtrToStringChars, how to free memory?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, memory, memory-management, c++-cli

I'm using PtrToStringChars method to get a pointer to character array held by a managed string. I'm then converting that character array to jstring and returning it to the calling function. Before doing this, how do I free up the memory occupied by the character array?
This is my code.

```
System::String *result=L"Checking";
const __wchar_t __pin * retVal = PtrToStringChars(result);
return env->NewString((jchar *)retVal,(jsize) wcslen(retVal));
```

Here, how do I free up the memory pointed by retval?

Comment: Unrelated: Mixing the JVM and CLR in the same process? Surely that must lead to problems somewhere...

Comment: @immibis ever heard of [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/)? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no memory that needs to be released, PtrToStringChars() returns an *interior pointer* that directly points at the System::String buffer.  The garbage collector knows how to find it back and update it when the buffer is moved.

You do indeed need to pin that pointer so the GC cannot move the buffer while the NewString() function is executing.  It is a very cheap kind of pinning, no handle gets created for it.  It is *very* important that NewString() copies the string content and not the passed pointer.  The pointer becomes invalid after code execution leaves the block that contains the pin.

You use old Managed C++ syntax, it has been deprecated for the past decade and will not work anymore in VS2015.  Proper C++/CLI syntax is:

```
System::String^ result = "Checking";
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> retVal = PtrToStringChars(result);
return env->NewString((jchar*)retVal, result->Length);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your retVal points to the actual buffer that the managed String object holds. The buffer is pinned (gc can't move/dismiss it) until the retVal goes out of scope, so you'd better make sure your env->NewString does not cache the pointer's value.
As for freeing the memory, since it's owned by the managed object, it will be handled by the garbage collector.